# How to create Javascript buttons that change image & each image links to url & active button has highight color

Tags: javascript, image, toggle

Using the example shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb) or code below shows how javascript buttons can be used to toggle between images (on button show bright lightbulb image on and off button shows dark lightbulb image).

But, I also need each image to link to a different url webpage when image (not button) is selected.

The button would control the image changing and each image when clicked would link to different url.

Is there also a way to create a color tint for the active button.

I would like to use this script repeatedly for several groups of buttons and images on the same page. I'm also open to any other scripting ideas.

The sample script below is javascript placed in body of html page:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif" style="width:100px">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>
```

Comment: And what did you try? Hint: image as a link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I tried for hours to insert several variations of code to make this work with no luck, including adding **a href** link and was sadly disappointed no matter how I rearranged...

Comment: haha.. keep practicing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the image in an anchor tag and then update the href attribute similarly to how the src attribute is updated on the img elements.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif';document.getElementById('myLink').href='http://www.google.com'">Turn on the light</button>

<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com">
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">
</a>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif';document.getElementById('myLink').href='http://www.yahoo.com'">Turn off the light</button>
```

Comment: wow... I had created almost identical code that I was gonna share. Anyway, take note that the use of inline script is generally discouraged... you may want to seperate the scripting using object.onclick or creating a click handler